# What is the best way to handle potential missing JSON fields?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, refactoring

I have a python script that is pulling JSON data from an external API. I want it to print the name, ID number, and owner Email address for each JSON dictionary. But not every entry has an ownerEmail, so if I try to print the field it errors out with `KeyError: 'ownerEmail'`. I used a try-except to get around this:

```
for i in range (len(jsList)):
    try:
        print("Name: %s , ID: %s , Email: %s" % (jsList[i]['name'], jsList[i]['id'], jsList[i]['ownerEmail'] ))
    except:
        print("Name: %s , ID: %s " % (jsList[i]['name'], jsList[i]['id'] ))
```

This works but honestly I just don't like the look of it. Is there a way to refactor the code so that it works without having to repeat 2/3 of the print statement on another line?

Comment: You can use `.get` on a dictionary which will return `None` by default, or you can specify a default return value as the second argument.

Comment: This question isn't about JSON; it's about a `dict`, which you just happen to have decoded from JSON.

Comment: You should avoid using bare `except:` handlers because they can hide unexpected errors.

Comment: Please share the entire error message. Why are you using the old `%` string formatting? Instead of `for i in range (len(jsList)):` and constantly having to do `jsList[i]`, why not use `for elem in js_list:` (notice the name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to use the `dict.get` function:

```py
# Iterate over the items in the list directly
for entry in jsList:
    # f-strings or str.format are preferred over % formatting
    print(f"Name: {entry.get('name')}, ID: {entry.get('id')}, ...")

    # for str.format, you could do
    print("Name: {}, ID: {}, Email: {}".format(entry.get('name'), entry.get('id'), entry.get('useremail')))
```

This will allow you to try to get a key without having to catch the `KeyError`:

```py
a = {'name': 'John', 'lastname': 'Doe'}

print(a.get('name'))
John

print(a.get('id'))
None

print(a.get('id', 0))
0
```

The second argument is what gets returned on default if the key is missing, if it is excluded, it will return `None`

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew there had to be a way to do it without needlessly repeating lines.